# Auto-plot country from ip address in excel

Tags: excel, networking, bigdata, business-intelligence

using Excel. I have approx 29 million records of data, here is the layout example.

[image]

I am looking to auto insert the origin country from the IP address.

I have tried multiple ways found online but they don't seem to work, I have tried https://www.ip2location.com/free/excel-addin for example. but I need a free source as this is for a school project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 29M records can hardly be considered a 'school project'. Projects developed in a learning environment are targeted at proof-of-concept, not commercial use.

Comment: You can export the list into CSV. Then download the free IP2Location App https://www.ip2location.com/free/applications and IP2Location LITE https://lite.ip2location.com database. After completed the processing, import the CSV back into Excel.

Comment: Thank you @Michael C. I am going to try this today, i will update if this works for everyone